# Hover event handler always fails

Tags: jquery, each, event-handling, mousehover

I want to create a super simple set of handlers for the hover() shortcut but i keep failing. I ultimately just went with mouseenter/mouseleave but I want to see what my problem is here for future purposes.

```
$function(){
     $('div.profile').find('li:gt(0)').each(function(){
           this.hover(highlight,offlight);
});
});

var highlight=function(){
   $(this).css("background","blue");
}

var offlight=function(){
   $(this).css("background","none");
}
```

Ok so this is probably riddled with errors.  First, I'm not sure if the "this" function context works in the second two functions definitions since this is not really defined outside of the ready handler.  If it doesn't work, can I do anything else here to make sure that the "li" which gets highlighted is the same one is hovered over?  Should I just make highlight and offlight anonymous functions or is there another way?

2) It seems as though my hover event handler fails no matter what I do.  I think that I'm using the each function correctly here.  I don't know what gives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `.hover()` on a DOM element. Call it on a jQuery object instead.

```
//-----v------was missing the "("
      $(function() {
           $('div.profile').find('li:gt(0)').hover(highlight,offlight);
      });
// attach .hover() to all the <li> found-------^
```

As you can see, there's  no need for the `.each()`.

---

Overall, I'd use the CSS `:hover` pseudo selector if all you're doing is a simple background change:

```
  $(function() {
       $('div.profile').find('li:gt(0)').addClass( "hoverMe" );
  });
```

*css*

```
li.hoverMe {
    background:none;
}
li.hoverMe:hover {
    background:blue;
}
```

Won't work in `IE6` without some tweaks to your markup though.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should just go with the css property.  This is also instructional for me (i'm trying to learn jquery) so the bigger question was why my .each() was failing.  But thanks for the heads up on calling it on the jQuery object.  That's an obvious mistake that I've seen but clearly forgot.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

In your `each` function, `this` does not reference a jQuery object. You need to wrap it in `$()`:

```
$(this).hover(highlight,offlight);
```

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. This is the way to do it.